# PHP namespace organisation, naming

Tags: php, namespaces, naming-conventions, php-5.3

I am facing the following problem :

- I have a namespace `Exception\*`,
  which contains several types of
  exceptions.
- I have a namespace `Exception\User\*`, which contains a
  specific kind of exceptions
  (`Forbidden`, `LoggedOut`...).

Where do I put the **`User`** base exception class, extended by `Forbidden` and `LoggedOut` :

- `Exception\User`, i.e. in the `Exception\*` namespace (better full name) ?
- `Exception\User\User`, i.e. in the `Exception\User\*` namespace (more consistent) ?
- `Exception\User\Exception`, i.e. I rename it to be the "base" exception of the `Exception\User\*` namespace (weird) ?

NB : the `User` exception class is not abstract.

**Precision : I've used an example with exceptions, this is just an example. I am really wondering about where to put/how to name a base class in a namespace tree.**

Thanks if you can help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception\User
Exception\User\Forbidden
Exception\User\LoggedOut
```

Answer (score 3):

How you design your code is really up to you. However, there were some guys, who already thought about this and defined the [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md). At all your concept seems not very usable. If something went wrong within the namespace `\My\Space` (I think) everybody would expect an exception from this namespace. Its easier to design the corresponding `try-catch`-clauses, if there is a logical link between the cause and the exception itself.

```
try {
    $x = new \My\Space\Class;
    $x->doSomething();
} catch (\My\Space\SomethingWentWrongException $e) {
    // something went wrong
} catch (\My\Space\Exception $e) {
    // something unexpected from this namespace went wrong
}
```

Update (reflecting the precision in the question):

I think, there are (lets say) 2.5 ways ;) You can put the base class in the namespace, where it is usually use/implemented/extended, e.g. `*\Filter\FilterInterface` and `*\Filter\ConcreteFilter`. The other solution is to put it one level up (`*\Filter`) and either name the sub-namespace after the interface/base-class, or just name it something else (thats the half solution). I prefer the last one, for example interface `*\Filter` and a concrete class `*\filters\SomeFilter` (and yes, my namespaces are in lowercase ;)).

The main point is, that you stay with your decision. Do not mix up multiple "styles".

Comment: The `Exception` thing is just an example, I'm not wondering on where to put my exceptions but were to put a base class in a namespace tree. I'll correct the question to be more clear.